# Check if product has tier pricing

Tags: magento, php

I am not that knowledgable with the Magento API yet, so I don't know where to search. 
I found in the docs `getTierPriceHtml($product)` but that doesn't really help me.

So, is there a function that I can call on my $product object (in a template) and check if the product has tier pricing? If there is no a direct function in existence, then a short workaround will also be helpful.

I tried `if (getTierPriceHtml($product) != null)....` but that didn't work and is quite an ugly approach anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it with `$product->getTierPrices()`. If that returns an empty array it means that it doesn't have any tier prices at all.